# Sashigane: The Fives Have It

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sup>This is an entry for [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #44: Introduce a new grid deduction genre to the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7080)</sup>

---

This is a Sashigane puzzle, where you divide the grid into L shapes.

Rules taken from [Nikoli](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/sashigane.html):

- Divide the grid into L shaped blocks - one block wide. All blocks must be L shaped.
- Cells with open circles form the knee (bend) in a block.
- The number in an open circle shows the number of cells in its block. Open circles without numbers may have any number of cells.
- Cells with arrows form one end of its block, the arrow points towards the knee of this block.
- The number of marks in a block (arrows or open circles) may be 0, 1, 2, or 3.

An example puzzle and its solution, taken from Nikoli:

[image: example puzzle]

[image: example solution]

Now, solve this puzzle:

[image: the real puzzle - see CSV file below]

Here is the puzzle in a [playable form](https://puzz.link/p?sashigane/10/10/p.kil4l.zoip5k5k5n5k5k5pizo.l4lgk.p). The link leads to a puzz.link editor (which has a timer, if you care about that).

First answer with a fully-explained logical solution path gets the checkmark.

CSV version:

```
,,,,,,◯,,←,
,4,,,◯,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,←,,,
,,,5,,5,,5,,
,,5,,5,,5,,,
,,,←,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,◯,,,4,
,↑,,◯,,,,,,
```

Comment: How could an open circle be 0?

Comment: An L shape may have an arrow on either end _and_ a circle at its bend, making 3 marks,  or it could have no marks at all, or be somewhere in between.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hooray! The answer is as follows:

> [image]

Solving progress:

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: Generally it is advised to not provide solutions without any adequate reasoning on these kinds of puzzles only to add it later.